# DATE_ADD example for BigQuery returning error

Tags: google-bigquery

Running examples from [BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#datetime-functions) and getting errors for intervals.

`SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE "2008-12-25", INTERVAL 5 DAY) as five_days_later;`

Returns...

`Error: Encountered " <STRING_LITERAL> "\"2008-12-25\" "" at line 1, column 22. Was expecting: ")" ... [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]`

What am I missing here? Legacy SQL is checked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Try below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE "2008-12-25", INTERVAL 5 DAY) AS five_days_later
```

... or just uncheck Legacy SQL :o)